# How does this Python import work

Tags: python

I'm working in a Python 2.7 project with the following layout

```
package
 - __init__.py
 - module_one.py
 - module_two.py
 - module_three.py
```

By convention we import things like `import package.module_one` and then call `package.module_one.do_something` So far so good. With only this import however, I can also call `package.module_two.do_something_else` without having to import `package.module_two`. I tried the same with Python 3.5 and I get `AttributeError: module 'package' has no attribute 'module_two'`. I would like to get rid of this magic and be forced to always having to import everything that I use or at least get some warning. Is there a way to do this? I tried Google but had a hard time finding the right term to find more information. Adding `from __future__ import absolute_import` has not effect, so it seems not to have anything to do with that.

Comment: Check content of `package/__init__.py`

Comment: `__init__.y` is empty, no magic there... I could even understand that I don't get an error if I'd also have a `import package` in the file (see http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-submodules-are-added-to-the-package-namespace-trap ), but I don't do that...

Comment: If `__init__.py` is empty then this shouldn't happen on either python version unless there is something importing `module_two` in `module_one.py`

Comment: I agree, it shouldn't happen, but it does ;-) I can do `import package.module_without_any_imports` and I can still call `package.module_one.do_something` without having a `import package.module_one`...

Comment: And there is another issue, if I have `import package.module_one` and `import package.module_two` but only call something on `package.module_one`, pylint does not give me an unused import warning for module_two.

Comment: If you're not sure where the module is imported from you can raise an exception at the beginning of the module, then you'll get a nice stack trace. Or run with `python -v`.

Comment: @mata that helped, when I removed all imports in other modules (I'll need them though), I did get an error. But I am still confused because I do not import `package` but `package.some_module`. So when I do `import package.some_module`, it is actually `package` that is added to the module's namespace and I am indeed bitten by http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-submodules-are-added-to-the-package-namespace-trap ?